# Restart blue splodge bug report GUI (when changing your mind about submitting a bug report)?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

Ok, so today I try to update, and during `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, I get a problem with Blender:

```
...
Setting up libasound2:i386 (1.1.3-5ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up blender (84452-d97df138d1a-0thomas~bionic0) ...
  File "/usr/share/blender/2.80/scripts/addons/io_convert_image_to_mesh_img/mesh/dtm.py", line 133
    num_labels = self.label.get(text='LABEL_RECORDS', 1)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

  File "/usr/share/blender/2.80/scripts/addons_contrib/curve_tools/Properties.py", line 39
    row.label(text="Sel:", nrSelectedObjects)
                          ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

  File "/usr/share/blender/2.80/scripts/addons_contrib/io_scene_cod/__init__.py", line 417
    col.label(text="Armature: %s" % armature_info, icon)
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

dpkg: error processing package blender (--configure):
 installed blender package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
...
done
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 blender
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

At when `apt` finished, at this point, I got a window with this blue splash icon, asking if I want to submit a bug. EDIT: managed to capture it on screenshot:

[image: ubuntu-apport]

Here I thought I'll just uninstall/reinstall blender, and get rid of the error, so I said no.

So I did uninstall/reinstall blender, but upon reinstall, got the same error. Except, I don't get the blue splodge icon or GUI for error reporting anymore.

Now, I know there is `ubuntu-bug`, but that one needs the name of the exact package failing - and here it is not `blender` per se crashing, it's the installation of `blender` via apt that is failing. And if I say `ubuntu-bug blender`, it will not auto-collect the failure that happened during `apt install`, so I have to manually type all that in. And why type all that in, when I know the system is perfectly capable of figuring the right error and right report on its own (otherwise I wouldn't have gotten the blue splodge icon GUI previously)?

So the question is - what is this blue splodge icon GUI for error reporting called (is it `apport`, or what is it), and how do I restart it again, in case `apt install` fails? And where are the logs for it kept?

Comment: While you happen to be using apt, those do not look like apt or dpkg errors. Those look like Blender 2.80 python errors. Since Blender 2.80 is not in the Ubuntu repositories (nor Debian yet), report the problem to whatever PPA or other non-Ubuntu source that you got the package from...so the apport (blue splodge) window won't help you much anyway.

Comment: Thanks @user535733 - great to have it confirmed that blue splodge is actually `apport` ! Indeed, I have `blender` installed from PPA, but I was sort of hoping that `apport` would take the URL of the PPA into account, and maybe post a bug on the respective page, I guess that is not how it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Indeed, happened again - and I tried to report, but cannot, `apport` says "The problem cannot be reported: This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again"

Comment: Got the same problem and even emailed thomas schiex over launchpad about and meanwhile an update happened so a new build is available, but it has the same problems as the one before.